# Formatting a string to be a constant length in Python

Tags: python, string, format

Lets say I have a few string titles:

```
title0 = 'USA'
title1 = 'Canada'
```

And I want to append a list of '#' characters to the front and back of these titles to give them a constant length so they look like:

```
######## USA ########
####### Canada ######
```

With 1 space buffering the start and end of the text.  Obviously I can't always get a symmetric number of symbols around the word.  Is there a way to do this with built in Python string formatting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python's `str.format()` has a few options that should get you what you want. You can read more about them [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). This should give you what you wanted.

```
title0 = '{:#^{width}}'.format(' USA ', width=19)
title1 = '{:#^{width}}'.format(' Canada ', width=19)
```

Or using a similar syntax for the [new f-strings/formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals):

```
width = 19
country = 'USA'
title0 = f'{country:#^{width}}'
```

Comment: That was precisely what I was looking for.  Thanks for the extra resources too.